# What to use as a unique hash in vercel KV database with NUXT and sidebase-auth?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

I'm confused as to what I should use as a unique hash for storing user information. `sidebase-auth` or `nuxt-auth` provides information about user such as display name, email and image url with github. I can use the name or email or both as a hash but if they change their name or email on github then that'll create problems. I can also ask the user to make a unique username but I can only do that after they log in. That means if they have changed their sensitive information such as email or name on github then I can't really fetch their data from vercel KV. What should I do?